# Validacion con PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero hacer un conteo de reportes mediante el status en el que se encuentran, tengo dos consultas una es

```
SELECT 
orden_trabajo.status, COUNT(id_orden) AS cuantas 
FROM orden_trabajo  
ORDER BY 
status;
```

El resultado de esta me arroja el numero total de ordenes que es `46`

la otra consulta es

```
SELECT 
orden_trabajo.status, COUNT(id_orden) AS cuantas 
FROM  
orden_trabajo where (fecha >= ? AND fecha <= ? ) 
ORDER BY 
status;
```

El resultado de esta me arroja dependiendo la fecha.

lo que queria yo es juntar las dos consultas en una condicion para que dependiendo valide si los campos en el formulario estan vacios o llenos, los cuales son dos fecha1 y fecha2

el codigo me quedo de la siguiente forma

```
 function total($fecha1,$fecha2){
   include("dbconnect.php");

   if ($_POST('#fecha1').val() === '' || $_POST('#fecha2').val() === '') { 
  ##### no se si en esta parte de la validacion estoy bien ########

   $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT orden_trabajo.status, COUNT(id_orden) AS    
   cuantas FROM orden_trabajo  ORDER BY status ");
   $sql->execute();
 if ($sql->rowCount () > 0){
   while($rows=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   echo "<strong><h2>El numero total de Ordenes: </h2></strong>";
   echo "<h1>".$rows['cuantas']."</h1>";

  }
 }else{
  echo "";
 }

 }else{
 $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT orden_trabajo.status, COUNT(id_orden) AS 
 cuantas FROM orden_trabajo where (fecha >= ? AND fecha <= ? ) ORDER BY 
  status ");
   $sql->bindParam(1,$fecha1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $sql->bindParam(2,$fecha2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $sql->execute();
 if ($sql->rowCount () > 0){
    while($rows=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo "<strong><h2>El numero total de Ordenes: </h2></strong>";
    echo "<h1>".$rows['cuantas']."</h1>";

    }
  }else{
   echo "";
  }
 }
}
```

En la parte resaltado con negro no estoy seguro de que haci se mande llamar los campos del formulario, porque en esa parte me manda error, quisiera saber si me podrian asesorar

Comment: Revisa bien tu código, por que lo que veo es que estas confundiendo JQuery con php en esta parte principalmente de código `$_POST('#fecha1').val()`

Comment: oh ya veo y entonces como podria mandar llamar el campo con codigo php?

Comment: ya quedo muchas gracias por tu ayuda `$fecha1 = $_POST['fecha1'];
  $fecha2 = $_POST['fecha2']; 
  if ($fecha1 == null || $fecha2== null) {`

Comment: añade la solución que encontraste  en la sección **Respuestas** para que otros usuarios puedan ver que solucionaste tu problema o que simplemente puedan consultar tu solución a un problema parecido, Slds!

Answer (score 0):

```
 function total($fecha1,$fecha2){
   include("dbconnect.php");

   $fecha1 = $_POST['fecha1'];
   $fecha2 = $_POST['fecha2']; 
   if ($fecha1 == null || $fecha2== null) {
   $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT orden_trabajo.status, COUNT(id_orden) AS    
   cuantas FROM orden_trabajo  ORDER BY status ");
   $sql->execute();
   if ($sql->rowCount () > 0){
   while($rows=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   echo "<strong><h2>El numero total de Ordenes: </h2></strong>";
   echo "<h1>".$rows['cuantas']."</h1>";

   }
   }else{
     echo "";
   }

   }else{
   $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT orden_trabajo.status, COUNT(id_orden) AS 
   cuantas FROM orden_trabajo where (fecha >= ? AND fecha <= ? ) ORDER BY 
   status ");
   $sql->bindParam(1,$fecha1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $sql->bindParam(2,$fecha2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $sql->execute();
  if ($sql->rowCount () > 0){
    while($rows=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo "<strong><h2>El numero total de Ordenes: </h2></strong>";
    echo "<h1>".$rows['cuantas']."</h1>";

     }
    }else{
     echo "";
    }
   }
  }
```